# How to read and write LocalMachine registry keys

Tags: c#, registry

Am developing a visio addin for my application in which i have a scenario where the user clicks on a button to update the registry keys which resides in LocalMachine.

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\VisioAddIn",true);


            if (setting.Name == "abc")
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default[setting.Name] = txtbox1.Text;
                if (registryKey != null)
                    registryKey.SetValue("abc", (txtbox1.Text).ToString());
        registryKey.Close();
            }

            if (setting.Name == "def")
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default[setting.Name] = txtbox2.Text;
                if (registryKey != null)
                {
                    registryKey.SetValue("def", (txtbox2.Text).ToString());
                    registryKey.Close();
                }
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But am getting the following error System.UnAuthorisedAccessException:Cannot write to the registry key.

If i run my visio addin in administrator mode this error wont occurs. But its not my solution. Please help me out.

Harish

Comment: Without elevated rights, you can only write to CurrentUser, not to to LocalMachine.

Answer (score -1):

I dont want to use HKCU as it saves for all users(in my case users will be more).I have a found a solution which we can elevate an UAC.

[Link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3#content)!